# How to design swing ui?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, user-experience

I want to create guis in java swing, however I find it difficult. I use intellij and it does not have a great edit or I am missing it. I wanted to create as a simple practice an UI that looks like code editor, so file structure view, code, input and output. This is what I got:

[image]

There are some problems, I cannot resize anything in application with my mouse, like i can in intellij, also even this bad looking thing took sooooo long to make that I just have to ask myself whats the deal with swing? So my question is how can I create something that looks like normal code editor and is there any free Swing GUI editing tool?

Answer (score 1):

One of the challenges with visual editors for Swing (or any other UI framework) is that they can generate really messy code.  My personal preference is to create GUI's by hand - but this means two things:

1. You need to learn how to use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) in Swing.  They allow you to position components on screen and determine how resizing (among other things) will work.  [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is very powerful.
2. You need to understand which components to use when.  If you want to drag and resize specific parts of your application, look at [Split Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html).

Alternatively, if you really want to use a GUI editor, also have a look at the one in [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

Comment: *"gui for desktops is in c#"* Java GUIs need to work across different platforms. look and feels etc. That's why we use layout managers to create them. The layout managers are responsible for determining the correct size and position of components.